# Entity created in postRemove Listener is not persisted

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am working on a Symfony 2.8 based project which is basically an online address book.

An `EntityDeletionListener` is used to handle `postRemove` events to add some information to a delete log which is needed for some internal book keeping:

```
class EntityDeletionListener implements EventSubscriber {
    public function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array('postRemove');
    }

    public function postRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if (!$entity->shouldAddToDeleteLog())
           return ;

        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $repo = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:DeleteLog');

        $log = $repo->createEntity();
        $log->setGuid($entity->getGuid());
        ...

        $em->persist($log);

        // Flush entity manager if not disabled in entity settings
        if ($entity->shouldFlushDeleteLog())
            $em->flush();
    }
}
```

This works without any problem: Each time a `Contact` entity is removed, the delete log entry is created automatically.

Now I am working on an option to bulk delete any number of selected `Contacts`. 
To speed up the process the entity manger is not flushed after every single remove operation but only after processing some batch.

```
class ContactRepository extends EntityRepository {
    public function bulkDelete($guids) {
        $this->_em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();

        try {
            $batchSize = 100;
            $currentBatch = 0;           

            foreach ($guids as $guid) {
                $contact = $this->findOneByGuid($guid);

                if ($contact) {        
                    // DO NOT FLUSH EVERY DELETE LOG
                    $contact->setDeleteLogFlush(false);

                    $this->_em->remove($contact);

                    $currentBatch++;
                    if ($currentBatch % $batchSize === 0)
                        $this->_em->flush();
                }
            }

            $this->_em->flush();  
            $this->_em->getConnection()->commit();
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {            
            $this->_em->getConnection()->rollBack();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem 1:**
If I use `$contact->setDeleteLogFlush(false)` to avoid flushing every DeleteLog automatically the `DeleteLogs` are not persisted at all. Also the `Contact` entities are remove correctly and the `postRemove` is executed for every remove operation, the logs are not persisted to the DB.

There is no exception or other error which would explain why the logs are not persisted. Even if there would be an error, in this case the complete transaction should fail and the `Contacts` would not be deleted as well. But they are deleted...

**Problem 2:**
If do NOT use `$contact->setDeleteLogFlush(false)` the `postRemove` listener flushes every new `DeleteLog`, I get the following exception as soon as more than one entry is deleted at once:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: "Type error: Argument 2 passed to Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::delete() must be of the type array, null given
```

How to solve this? Why are the logs created in the `postRemove` listener not persisted when flushing the entity manager?

Comment: Didn't read all the question but I would suggest not to persist logs in the database (or better not in a relational database). You'll be in trouble if those entities grows (in number) and you'll be in trouble when quering the table. Use a file or a NoSQL db for those kind of operations

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you want to create and delete multiple `Contact` entities but you're doing it in the wrong event because as stated in the [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events)

> The postRemove event occurs for an entity after the entity has been
>   deleted. It will be invoked after the database delete operations. It
>   is not called for a DQL DELETE statement.

and you should not do any changes to database as [stated here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#postupdate-postremove-postpersist)

> postUpdate, postRemove, postPersist
>
> The three post events are called inside EntityManager#flush(). Changes
>   in here are not relevant to the persistence in the database, but you
>   can use these events to alter non-persistable items, like non-mapped
>   fields, logging or even associated classes that are not directly
>   mapped by Doctrine.

So I would just move the whole `postRemove` logic to `preRemove` event since

> The preRemove event is called on every entity when its passed to the
>   EntityManager#remove() method. It is cascaded for all associations
>   that are marked as cascade delete.